# How can I convert "11/23/2014 8:35 PM" to "2014-11-16 07:45:00" in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using rails 4.1 and Ruby 2.1.

I am getting "11/23/2014 8:35 PM" passed to the server as part of a form using [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker), and I would like to convert it like this (or something similar):

```
pu = "11/23/2014 8:35 PM".to_time #or something like this
@appointment = @car.appointments.build(pickuptime: pu)
```

This `.build` call is expecting the time to be formatted as `2014-11-16 07:45:00`. How can I make this conversion? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/DateTime.html#M000214) and specify the format as the second parameter

```
pu = DateTime.strptime("11/23/2014 8:35 PM", "%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p")
@appointment = @car.appointments.build(pickuptime: pu)
```